# TypeScript: Assign new Observable to initialized Observable variable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

Just to check if there are no hidden catches in this one.

Imagine a situation with a component with **@Input()** setter function, where the private variable is set together with an NgRx selector assigned to another variable:

```
private _inputValue: SomeDto;
asyncProperty$: Observable<boolean>;

@Input() set someValue(inputValue: SomeDto) {
  this._inputValue = inputValue
  this.asyncProperty$ = this.store.select(fromStore.selectSomeValue());
  // and some other logic...
}
```

In HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="asyncProperty$ | async" class="testClass">...</div>
```

Is it safe to assign new Observable to `asyncProperty$` variable each time the component input changes? I have a strange feeling I should rather avoid this approach but can't tell why.

Comment: `async` will unsubscribe when `asyncProperty$` changes and also Observables do nothing until you subscribe to them so you should be fine here.

Comment: I’d say this is safe but I’d question why you need to do it? Whatever you’re doing could probably be done better with operators.

Comment: As @bryan60 suggests, this will work, but there may be a better way to do it - if you're using NgRx, I'd consider creating combined selectors using [createSelector](https://ngrx.io/api/store/createSelector) and ditch the `@Input`, not a big deal here, but a nice feature of NgRx to get into...

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that. This was just a strange case that popped up to me while checking PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on martin's comment, Angular's change detection will trigger when the `@Input` value changes. During the [component's life-cycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) Angular will unsubscribe from Observables passed to the `async` pipe, and in this case, subscribe to the new one that has been pass to `async`.